# Python tuple combination

Tags: python

I have list of tuples like :

```
data = [(10, 11, 12), (13, 14, 15), (16, 17, 18)]
```

and I want output like :

```
[(10, 13, 16), (10, 13, 17), (10, 13, 18),
 (10, 14, 16), (10, 14, 17), (10, 14, 18),
 (10, 15, 16), (10, 15, 17), (10, 15, 18),
 (11, 13, 16), (11, 13, 17), (11, 13, 18),
 (11, 14, 16), (11, 14, 17), (11, 14, 18),
 (11, 15, 16), (11, 15, 17), (11, 15, 18),
 (12, 13, 16), (12, 13, 17), (12, 13, 18),
 (12, 14, 16), (12, 14, 17), (12, 14, 18),
 (12, 15, 16), (12, 15, 17), (12, 15, 18)]
```

Can anyone help me to get this output using python ??

Comment: Can you help us with your code?